# Remove leading zero to compare negative calculation to what is displayed on UI

Tags: ruby

I'm using Watir with Ruby and need to remove a leading zero to compare a negative calculation to what is displayed in the UI.

The calculation results in `-0.11`.

```
roi = (((incrementGrossMargin.to_f - Funding.to_f)/Funding.to_f).round(2))
```

On the UI, it is displayed as `-.11`.

I'm trying to confirm what is displayed on the UI matches the calculation, and that the UI does NOT display the leading zero.

```
puts "#{roi}  ROI correct"  if total.text.include?
```

How can I get rid of the leading `0` in the calculation to so that it compares as true to what is displayed on the UI?

Comment: Just cast both to float...

Comment: What range of results can the calculation return? I mean, can it be greater than 1? How are you displaying that?

Comment: Your code is not valid Ruby. If you intended to interpolate `puts` within `puts`, that is also meaningless as it evaluates to `nil`. And, what is `total`? What is `text`? Don't introduce things that are irrelevant. Write something minimal.

Comment: Yes, the calculation can be greater than zero.  It is displayed rounded to 2 decimal places;  123.45

Answer (score 3):

In order to trun the resulting *Float* number to this `"-.11"` format you should remove a *String* from the *Float* and then remove the `0` from it

```
-0.11.to_s.sub(/^(-)?0\./,'\1.') #=> "-.11"

-1.11.to_s.sub(/^(-)?0\./,'\1.') #=> "-1.11"

 1.11.to_s.sub(/^(-)?0\./,'\1.') #=> "1.11"
```

Comment: @user3014173 -- since this answer has addressed your question, you should accept it (so that SO stays tidy).